# malformed header from script 'test.py': Bad header: FISCAL_WEEK_NUMBER ., referer: http://localhost/test.html

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to run pyhton cgi. on apache wamp server. HTML side of the code works fine but when it turns to the python script. I get the following error:

> malformed header from script 'test.py': Bad header:
>   FISCAL_WEEK_NUMBER        ., referer: http://localhost/test.html

I tried testing my python code separately on IDE an it works fine. I am unable to find the issue around here. Below is my code:

```
#!C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/python.exe

import cgi
import os
import cgitb;
import pandas as pd
import teradata
import numpy as np

os.environ["USERNAME"] = "hjoshi"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get filename here.
fileitem = form['filename']

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.file:
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    query = "insert into p_piw_stg.sales_goals_test_harsh (?, ?, ?, ?)" #insert query for database
    input = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/hjoshi/Downloads/' + fn)
    test = pd.DataFrame(input, columns = ["FISCAL_WEEK_NUMBER", 'STORE_NUMBER', 'DEPARTMENT', 'SALES_GOAL_AMOUNT']) #creating a dataframe
    #print(test)
    num_of_chunks = len(test)
    host,username,password = 'someIP','elt_usr', 'elt_usr'
    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
    with udaExec.connect (method="odbc",system=host, username=username, password=password, driver="Teradata") as con:
        chunks = np.array_split(test, num_of_chunks)
        for i,row in enumerate(chunks):
            print(row)
            data = [tuple(x) for x in chunks[i].to_records(index=False)]
            con.executemany(query, data, batch=True)

    message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'

else:
    message = 'No file was uploaded'

print ("""
Content-Type: text/html\n\r\n
<html>
<body>
   <p>%s</p>
</body>
</html>
""" % (message,))
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution for above problem, by having the code

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\r\n")
```

at the top right after writing the imports. code was not able to identify the html header which is supposed to come first.